# jQuery Disable buttons but not Click Event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Asp.net web application. 
On the Client Side, I would like to disable two buttons: resubmitOlderButton and  createUploadPackageButton when the createUploadPackageButton is clicked.
The code below disables the buttons, however, it also disables the entire createUploadPackageButton Event which I don't want. The code in the button Event is written in C#.  I only want to disable the button not the Event.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#createUploadPackageButton").click(function () {
        if ($("#startDateTextBox").val() != '' && $("#endDateTextBox").val() != ''){
            $("#resubmitOlderButton").attr("disabled", true);//disable clicked button
            $("#createUploadPackageButton").attr("disabled", true); //disable clicked button
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "it also disables the entire createUploadPackageButton Event"?

Comment: Also, I think jQuery.prop() should be used instead of jQuery.attr()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to finish an action of the clicked button (for example, submit the form) and then disable the button you need to add some delay. Disabled button do not submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#createUploadPackageButton").click(function () {
        if ($("#startDateTextBox").val() != '' && $("#endDateTextBox").val() != ''){
            $("#resubmitOlderButton").prop("disabled", true);//disable clicked button
            setTimeout(function(){$("#createUploadPackageButton").prop("disabled", true);},100); //disable clicked button
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have button A and button B , you are disabling both when button A is clicked. 
Now the click event will not work since you have **disabled** it. In your case - **createUploadPackageButton**.
Maybe try to disable button A and B using a third button C.